# How to use New-Object of a class present in a C# DLL using PowerShell--different data types

Tags: c#, list, object, dll, powershell

Edit: Added the Powershell code that uses the C# Objects. Really Easy To do it all in C# and work with it in Powershell. Thank you!

I'm making two objects in C# that I use in my PowerShell Code. I want to make a FeatureObject, set its variables; then make FeatureAttributes and add it to the list in the FeatureObject. I can set and get the strings, ints, ect.--but I'm having trouble adding the FeatureAttribute to the List in the FeatureObject.

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class FeatureObject {
    public string layerName;
    public int numFeatures;
    public string geometry;
    public string unit;
    List<FeatureAttr> objFtcAttr;
    public FeatureObject()
    {
        objFtcAttr = new List<FeatureAttr>();
    }   
    public List<FeatureAttr> ftcAttr { get; set; }
} 

public class FeatureAttr {
    public string AttrKeyName;
    public string AttrDataType;
    public string AttrNumericRange;
    List<String> allValuesOfAttr = new List<String>();
    public void setValueOfAttr (string value) {
            this.allValuesOfAttr.Add(value);
    }
    public List<String> getValuesOfAttr() {
        return(this.allValuesOfAttr);
    }
}
```

PS

```
Add-Type -Path C:\projects\bin\FCObject.dll
$ftcObj = New-Object FeatureObject
$ftcAttr = New-Object FeatureAttr
$ftcObj = New-Object FeatureObject
$ftcObj.geometry = $geometry
$ftcObj.ftcAttr.Add($ftcAttr)
```

Also: Do I always need to explicitly declare my getters and setters like below and above? Can't I just get and set the data like $ftcObj.geometry = $geometry ??

```
public string geometry
    {
        get { return geometry; }
        set { geometry = value; }
    }
```

or

```
public string geometry {get; set; }
```

Help Please!

Comment: What have you tried for adding to the list?  What error(s) did you get?  Since the code you included doesn't initialize the 'ftcAttr' list, perhaps FeatureObject should follow the same pattern and just have a getter and use a field init to instantiate it.  You can instantiate generic types in PowerShell, but it's a little painful, so if you can avoid that and just let it call methods on an existing List<FeatureAttr> you should find things easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably modify `FeatureObject` to instantiate a default list:

```
public class FeatureObject 
{
    public FeatureObject()
    {
        ftcAttr = new List<FeatureAttr>();
    }
    public List<FeatureAttr> ftcAttr {get; set; }
}
```

Then you just start adding things to it in PowerShell.

If you want to create it in PowerShell, use this syntax:

```
$ftcObj = New-Object FeatureObject
$ftcObj.ftcAttr = New-Object 'Collections.Generic.List[FeatureAttr]'
```

You must quote the type string for the generic list and you must use the full, namespace-qualified type name for `FeatureAttr`.

Finally, it doesn't matter if you explicitly declare your properties, or use C#'s auto-property syntax.  Auto-properties get converted by the compiler into explicit getters/setters.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comments--give me a few to implement and I'll get back with you all.